# Why does my Alesia Melody 61 Keyboard keys replay itself after I release the key?

Tags: piano, keyboard

I press down on my keyboard key and it repeats the sound. I press it, it makes the sound, but then when I release it and lift my finger off of it it plays the sound again. I don’t know what’s wrong with it and I need help. I’m just a beginner and self taught so I don’t know much about pianos just yet.

Comment: Has it done this from new - is it new?